# How to scroll in a Gtk::ScrolledWindow to a specific row from a Gtk::TreeView

Tags: treeview, gtk, scrolledwindow

I have a `Gtk::TreeView` inside a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow`. At one point I get a `Gtk::TreeRow` row. How can I know if the row is in the visible area and how can I scroll the ScrolledWindow so that the row will be visible?

L.E.: I found the sollution:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeModel> model = pSEMQueueTreeView->get_model();
Gtk::TreeModel::Children children = model->children();
Gtk::TreeModel::Children::iterator it;

it = children.begin();

pSEMQueueTreeView->scroll_to_row(model->get_path(it));
```